# Filtering Sentinel 1 Image Collection to my area of interest produced no feature (or image) in google-earth-engine

Tags: filtering, google-earth-engine, sentinel1

My objective it to load and filter 2015 to 2016 sentinel images for my project area (AOI); The code produced image collection without image. Can you help me

The following is the code originally from https://krstn.eu/analyze-Sentinel-1-time-series-in-Google-Earth-Engine it does not work for my project area. It results in o elements in the image collection

Load the Sentinel-1 ImageCollection.

```
var sentinel1 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD');
```

Filter VH, IW

```
var vh = sentinel1
  // Filter to get images with VV and VH dual polarization.
  .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VH'))
  // Filter to get images collected in interferometric wide swath mode.
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
  // reduce to VH polarization
  .select('VH')
  // filter 10m resolution
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('resolution_meters', 10));
// Filter to orbitdirection Descending
var vhDescending = vh.filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'DESCENDING'));
// Filter time 2015
var vhDesc2015 = vhDescending.filterDate(ee.Date('2015-01-01'), ee.Date('2015-12-31'));
```

Filter to MKD AOI

```
var AOI = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[40.5548410121811,6.969011579129182],
        [39.0332345668686,7.241560288027144],
        [37.5226144496811,7.050793118016936],
        [37.9675607387436,6.521691240305265],
        [39.6539621059311,6.390691419627786],
        [40.5548410121811,6.969011579129182]]]);
var s1_mkd = vhDesc2015.filterBounds(AOI);
print(s1_mkd,'s1_mkd');
```

The following is the output of the print

```
ImageCollection COPERNICUS/S1_GRD (0 elements)
type: ImageCollection
id: COPERNICUS/S1_GRD
version: 1533921047325895
bands: []
features: []
properties: Object (15 properties)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are simply no images matching your criteria. For some parts of the world, Sentinel-1 imagery weren't acquired at full operational capacity until mid-late 2016. Change your date range in `filterDate()` to include more recent imagery (e.g., all of 2017 or 2018) and you will start seeing something closer to the Sentinel-1 12-day revisit.